# How to setup a WordPress website on free account of Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

Can any body point me to the steps to setup and run WordPress website on free account of Google App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions are [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).

Note: There is no free tier for Google CloudSQL. If you blog changes infrequently then you can minimize the cost of CloudSQL by using aggressive batcache settings.